# How to access the interaction with my Python chat bot on Heroku

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, chatbot, continuous-deployment, feedback

I am deploying my first coding project, using Heroku. An AI Python chat bot (html, css, javascript, flask for the front end). I am looking for the best way to see the input of the visitors once it is live, so I can add answers to new questions and keep improving it. Is this something that I should add to my codebase (before deploying) or through Heroku (after deploying)? Or...? Any tips/links to point me in the right direction are very welcome!

I checked the info on Heroku on prepping my codebase for deployment and elsewhere online. Not knowing if there is a staging option when/after deploying I haven't deployed the bot yet (my last step was connecting my Heroku account to my GitHub repo).